# Wait for element in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I followed what was written here:
[WebDriver Selenium API: ElementNotFoundErrorException when Element is clearly there !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112180/webdriver-selenium-api-elementnotfounderrorexception-when-element-is-clearly-the)

My code looks like:

```
    Function<WebDriver, WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
    return new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
          }
       };
    }

   ....... 

   driver.get(baseUrl);

   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("classname")));
   findByClassAndName(driver, "x-tree3-node-text", "Name1").click();
```

Problem is, that is does not seem to do anything. It doesn't work and i can't even see slightest trace of waiting for webpage gui. i got the same with implicit wait through timeouts... Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

Create function as follows :

```
public void Wait (string element)          // Wait function to wait for element
        { 
            for (int second = 0; ; second++)
                {
                    if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                    try
                    {
                        if (IsElementPresent(By.LinkText(element))) break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                 }  
        }
```

and now call this function where you want to wait for element as follows:

```
string element="<element name>";
        Wait(element);
```

Comment: In general using explicit sleep's is not a good way so i tried to avoid it.

Comment: Agreed, I hate having to use the whole explicit sleep. It's ugly and not good practice. However some times, it does the job...until a proper fix can be put in place.

If only Selenium Webdriver had easier functions for waiting :>

Answer (score 1):

You have to **catch Throwables** throwed from ExpectedCondition or your Function (the apply() methods is good place for that) and **return null so Wait.until() continues** to run - see http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/05/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part.html for detailed example.