# Is it possible to implicity wait for a value to change in Selenium 2.0?

Tags: ajax, selenium

I see many examples of waiting for html controls to become "present" , ie as a result of an ajax call, java event handler, and so on.

But in my case, my ajax code does not instantiate, or make visible, a new control; it repopulates existing controls with new values.

What I want to do is implicitly wait for these values to "show up", but I can't tell if this is possible in Selenium 2.0?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has two types of wait commands

**1** `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

**2** `WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element)`

The Example from:
[How can I ask the Selenium-WebDriver to wait for few seconds in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds) 
shows something which you may be able to use

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator) {
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Also check http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since those elements already exist, if you use `findElement()` on those elements, then you'll avoid StaleReferenceException's, and you'll be fine.

Your test flow would look something like this (mind you this is using the framework found [here](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium)

```
@Config(url="http://systemunder.test", browser=Browsers.CHROME)
public class MyTest extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        click(By.id("somethingThatTriggersAjax")
        .validateText(By.id("existingId"), "test");  // this would work.. 
    }
}
```

Using the framework there, it's much easier, and handles it's own waits, as well as accounts for ajax. however if you prefer vanilla -

```
public void test() {
    WebElement element;
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("somthingThatTriggersAjax"));
    // now ajax has done something.
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("existingId")); // now this will be updated with the new element information.
}
```

An alternative to these two solutions, would be to use `WebDriverWait`'s.. In your case, it'd be something like...

```
WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textPresentIn(By.id("existingId"), "some text you'd expect"));
```

Comment: Any idea how to do that in Python?  I have 

WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.ID("tp0_fuel_price"), "40"))

by By.id is not a function in Python's Selenium as it appears it is in Java. In short, I can't figure out how to specify the "locator" parameter to the text_to_be_present_in_element function..

Comment: I think I have my own answer. Here seems to be the way to do it:  WebDriverWait(ff, 5).until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element([By.ID,"tp0_fuel_price"], "3.40"))