# Java AWT Robot + Selenium: How to get back hold of the web elements after sending key events

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, awt, awtrobot

I have written the following code to handle a native OS pop up that is raised after clicking on a verification link in a webpage. It almost works, except that after the key presses are sent away to the pop up and next page is loaded I don't have control over my driver anymore. No Selenium code I have tried after, seems to be able to work properly. Either a `WebDriverException` is raised (from some internal `Selenium Javascript` file) or a time out Exception is raised. I've experimented with getting the page handle and trying to switch back to it, explicitly wait with `FluentWait` until an element in the new page is present and have tried different Selenium code after with no avail. Any cues to understand the problem here is much appreciated.

Here is my Java code snippet with some inline comments:

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); //Saving the window handle to switch to it later
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("https://mysite/login"); //Website with native OS pop up for authentication

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".loginbox")).click();

    //Convenience method to send a series of key codes to java.awt.Robot
    sendKeySequence(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    //TRYING TO GET HOLD OF THE WEB ELEMENTS AGAIN: Nothing works!

    //1st try: fluentWait(By.id("BigBox")).click(); //Method to wait until WebDriver element is present on the page

    //2nd try: driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    //driver.get("www.google.com");
```

`sendKeySequence` Implementation:

```
  private void sendKeySequence (int... commandStream) {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    for (int keyCode : commandStream) {
      robot.keyPress(keyCode);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    }
  }
```

PS! For the `fluentWait` implementation refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859689/1075499)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the robot like this (**Assuming* you need to press 2 TAB keys and 1 Enter Key using Robot class**):

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Then, try waiting for the new element in the page, using the below code:

```
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//xpath of the element")));
        element.click();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println("Error came while waiting and clicking the element. "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: My `sendKeySequence` method presses and releases keys in order and I don't even need to look for an element for it fail! Simply invoking `driver.get("www.google.com")` causes an exception `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException JavaScript Error: "a is null" ...` However looking for an element through your `WebDriverWait` results in an element not found exception after the time is run out

Comment: **sendKeySequence**; this an user-defined method ? Because I don't see any methods of such in the **Robot class** of **java.awt** package as you can see here: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Comment: yes it basically sends each key and releases it in a loop. I added the implementation to the post

Comment: yes, I'm using `java.awt.Robot` for which you posted the javadoc link.

Comment: @SabaAhang : What I meant, is the classname of the java file you're executing.. Is that **Robot** too ? If it is then change its name to **`Robot1`** or something different and use the code like this: **`Robot1 robot = new Robot1();     robot.sendKeySequence(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`**

Comment: Not really, I removed the confusing bit. There is no Robot class of my own. You can imagine the `sendKeySequence` is defined right in the same class where this code is defined. And this class is not called Robot

Comment: I tried the similar thing at my end with different site. It seems to be working after the **robot-code-sequence** is executed. It will be certainly helpful if you can provide the URL of the site (if it's public o'course). Thanks. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not public! The pop up is not Javascript but rather an OS Level pop up for id card authentication. In your example code, can you run any Selenium code after the Robot commands? Looking for an element or loading a new page both works? I suspect there is a synchronization issue between where the Robot commands are sent and were Selenium pick up the Thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66243/discussion-between-subh-and-saba-ahang).