# Thread.sleep() being ignored by selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep, thread-sleep

I have a selenium test that works great while debugging and stepping slowly through. I added a `Thread.Sleep()` in order to stop selenium while a file is downloaded. However selenium in completely ignoring the `Thread.Sleep()`. Any thoughts?

```
IWebElement iframe = driver.FindElement(By.Id("genFrame"));
CurrentFrame = driver.SwtichTo();
CurrentFrame.Frame(iframe);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("date").Sendkeys("05/11/2021" + Keys.Enter));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("export-btn"));
System.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep` is just trying to guess if download has finished. You need to use some other approach, for example - monitoring [download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586602/wait-for-finished-download-file-in-selenium-and-c-sharp).

Comment: @GuruStron your link just take me to another SO solution using thread.sleep().

Comment: It uses some code besides `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

In all possibilities `System.Thread.Sleep()` is never ignored unless some previous line of code raises an exception.

---

As per your code the unit is ***milliseconds***, so effectively **5000** milliseconds, i.e. **5** seconds.

---

### Solution

You may like to increase the waiting time to greater value, e.g. 10 seconds or more:

```
using System;  
using System.Threading;

System.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

---

### Update

As you can visually see selenium add the date field, possibly the line in the mid:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("export-btn"));
```

raises an exception.

Comment: I have increased the time to a silly number to ensure the sleep is being seen. I visually see selenium add the date field, then immediately close the driver.  I assure you the sleep is completely being ignored for some reason.

Comment: @Bean0341 _immediately close the driver_: Possibly the line in the mid `driver.FindElement(By.Id("export-btn"));` raises an exception?