# Promise executes too early

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriverjs

The WebDriverJS [API](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows) says I can write code like this:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("btnG")).click();
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
 console.log(title);
 //assertEquals("webdriver - Google Search", title);
});
```

Here title is "Google".  I can modify the code:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click().then(function(){
  /*WebDriverWait.until(function() {
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log(title);
      title = "webdriver - Google Search"
    });
  });*/

  driver.sleep(3000).then(function() {
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log(title);
    });
  });
});
```

And now the title is "webdriver - Google Search".  The promise changes status before the page has a chance to load. This example comes from the API documentation so it should work.

I saw an example of [waiting on SO,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds) however I do not not know to translate this to working code in WebDriverJS and the API makes no mention of "until".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how to use `wait` and `until` in the source code here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#653

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log(title);
    return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
  });
}, 1000).then(function() {
  console.log('done!')
});

driver.quit();
```

Gives the output:

```
webdriver - Google Search
done!
```

Comment: I don't see `Webdriver.prototype.until` defined in the link.  I am unable to get this to function in any way that solves the problem.  The code simply tries once and fails out.

Comment: Sorry - original was overly complex, you can just wait on the promise from `getTitle.then` based on the following from the docs:

> Each call to then() will return a new promise that represents the observer's result. If the callback (or errback) returns a value (no return is treated as returning undefined), the promise will be resolved.

It wont resolve unless your return is true, so it will time out after trying for 1000ms.

Comment: The documentation should say "If the callback (or errback) returns a **truthy** value (no return is treated as returning undefined), the promise will be resolved."  The truthy value causes the next `then` in the sequence to execute.

Comment: Note that this answer shows me how to get the effect of a `wait` without actually using `wait`.  I still do not know if `wait` is exposed on the WebDriverJS API.