# WebDriverWait timeout waits for the driver implicit timeout instead of the explicit timeout provided

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using python with Selenium WebDriver to test an angular based web-app.

In the login helper subroutine, on login, I want to check if it was successful before continuing with rest of the tests.

For this , I have the following piece of code:

```
login_success = WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"hr-landing")))

if login_success:
    self.logger.info("Looks like login was successful")
else:
    login_errors = self.get_login_errors()
    self.logger.debug(login_errors)
```

The problem I am facing is with the first line in the code. For a successful login, it returns quickly as the class 'hr-landing' is found.

However, for a failed login, that class is not found , and I wish for the Wait to timeout in 5 seconds as specified in my call to WebDriverWait.

However, the call times out only after 30 seconds (which is the implicit wait I have set on my driver)

How can I get around this issue ? I feel there is no point to providing the explicit timeout , because it is still respecting the implicit one.

Thanks a lot !
Moez.

Comment: get_login_errors contain implicity waits?

Comment: I call self.driver.implicitly_wait(30) once at beginning of the test harness -- and that wait setting is persisting in my login methods -- not only persisting , but it is given priority over the explicit wait provided to WebDriverWait

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue generally we face when both implicit and explicit waits are used. On fail get_login_errors() is called so i am expecting it have implicit waits.

To avoid such issues i hope good to use fluent waits which explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds-in-java)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Is there a python equivalent to fletnwait?

Comment: Hi looks like fluentwait is not available in python. in same link there is way in python to check elements by explicit wait. def conditions(driver):
    flag = True
    ticker = driver.find_elements_by_id("textbox")
    if not ticker:
        flag = False
    return flag

... click something to load ...
self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
self.wait.until(conditions)